# Apache allow all sites to use .htaccess file

Tags: apache

On our Apache server no users can upload the .htaccess file. They get a critical error when upload just this file via FTP. We can upload all other file types just fine. Is there a way I can allow this permission across all my sites?

Comment: Are permissions set correctly?

Comment: "a critical error" — Which says what? Have you checked the error log files?

Comment: "no users can upload the .htaccess file" — Any .htaccess file? Or just ones with specific directives? Have you tried uploading a blank file?

Comment: "error when upload just this file via FTP" — Does the HTTP server throw an error message or does the FTP server / client throw it?

Comment: I'd say Apache doesn't play any role in FTP uploads. It's either a specific issue with whatever FTP server software you use or a more generic one with SELinux or equivalent security tools.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in the end by adding the following lines to the vhost config for the site:

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
Require all granted